# unusual questions regarding controlling polarized light with LCD shutters

Tags: optics, visible-light, polarization

1) Is it correct to assume that if a light is already polarized one of the polarizers on the LCD shutter itself is not required to be present to selectively block it?

2) Is it correct to assume that if one of the polarizers from an LCD shutters is removed, then it can be used to always pass light of one polarization but selectively block light of the opposite polarization?

The reason I ask these questions comes down to me not really understanding what the liquid crystal layer actually does. My understanding was it acts as a controllable rotator so two same-angle polarizers before and after it would block 50% of unpolarized light but when it was switched on it would rotate the polarized light which hadn't been filtered by the first polarizer and wouldn't be filtered with the next polarizer as well to the opposite polarization state so it would get filtered as well, but I have no way to verify this currenty without sacrificing an LCD shutter.

Comment: I could tell you the answer, but if you discover the answer yourself it will be better.  Maybe you can get a very old digital watch with an LCD display and sacrifice it.

Comment: I could respond to your comment but if you guess what it is it will be better. Maybe you can actually give an answer in a literal Q&A site. Many things can go wrong tryping to peel off a polarizer film off of a thin glass. Just broke one and nearly sliced my finger. Not the best idea to learn by experimenting with this.